# Referring to wild animals as "game"

Tags: meaning

I am reading stories by Jack London, and I have noticed that often wild animals are referred to as *game*. It sounds funny to my non-English-native speaker ear. Is there some reason why the word *game* is used? Or did the word have a different meaning 100 years ago?

Comment: It's because the wild animals taste "gamy."  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of the word *game*, meaning something with rules done primarily for fun or to pass the time - that also applies to the ritualized hunting practices of the medieval upper classes. *Game animals* and *game birds* are ones that were hunted for sport - deer, elk, pheasant, quail, and a variety of other fowl - and then eaten (even though foxes and other animals are also traditionally hunted for sport, as they are not eaten they are not game).

As the European upper classes began colonizing the rest of the world, they began hunting new and unique animals, terming them *big game* (lions, elephants, rhinoceroses, etc), even though the meat was not always eaten afterward.

In the contexts like naturist writings, wilderness fiction or explorers' monogrphas, *game* alone usually refers to an animal of the deer family, or the meat thereof.

Answer (score 2):

It does indeed come from the fact hunting animals is a game or sport.

From the Middle English 'gamen' which meant sport.

[Source](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/game)